# XUL Richlistbox selection issue

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have a richlistbox on my firefox extension as follows:

```
<richlistbox id="accList" class="accList" seltype="single" flex="1">
    <richlistitem id ="accListTemplate" hidden="true">
        <listcell class="sessionActivate"/>
        <listcell class="nameItem"/>
        <listcell class="lastUsedItem"/>
        <spacer flex="1" />
        <listcell class="sessionDelete" />
        <listcell class="sessionComplete" />
        <listcell class="sessionDetails" />
    </richlistitem>
</richlistbox>
```

Through Javascript i clone this richlistitem and add it to the richlistbox with the values i want.

The result is:

[image: Listbox multiple selection]

The items all appear to be selected and i am not able to change that selection.

Another weird thing is, if i click on one of the lines and do:

```
alert(document.getElementById("accList").selectedCount);
```

it says 0.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden or not, the list selects the first item automatically - and when you clone it you get its "selected" state as well. Easiest solution: just don't put your template inside the `<richlistbox>` tag, put it somewhere outside.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way you're cloning the first item in the list you're getting some extra properties from that item you weren't expecting.  The first item in a list like this inherits these properties.

In your clone code remove the attributes `selected` and `current` before you append your items into the list.

Example:

```
var newtemplate = document.getElementById("accListTemplate").cloneNode(true);
newtemplate.removeAttribute("hidden");
newtemplate.removeAttribute("id");
newtemplate.removeAttribute("current");
newtemplate.removeAttribute("selected");
// do your content manipulation
document.getElementById("accList").appendChild(newtemplate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works well, but i ended up using the way Wladimir wrote on the other answer.